# Is there a maximum image file size that can be upload to sharelatex?

Tags: graphics, sharelatex

I am currently writing a masters thesis and have some pretty high resolution images I need to include, the raw files were about 600 mb but I compressed them to about 80mb in the .png format. However whenever I try to upload it to sharelatex it stops at about 40% and I get the message "Failed :(". I was therefore wondering if there is a maximum file size limit or a storage limit that I have reached. If there is no limit, what can the cause be? I dont get any error logs only the "Failed :(" message.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: What's preventing you installing LaTeX locally?

Comment: what resolution are you using to print your thesis?

Comment: Hi, the reason for me not installing it locally is because I am not so knowledgeable about computers in general and sharelatex is very easy to use. Im printing the thesis in standard A4 format and I realise now how silly it was to have such huge photos, a friend of mine reccomended to resample and resize the images in photoshop something that resolved the problem :).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved resizing the images in photoshop as indicated in the OP's comment.